# How to use Proximity Sensor in Android Programming

Tags: android, proximitysensor

I know that there are only two values of proximity : 0.0 & 1.0

I need a simple code to detect proximity through the device's sensors, and perform any task if proximity changes to `1.0`

Answer (score 2):

this is what i found.

```
public class SensorActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
 private SensorManager mSensorManager;
 private Sensor mSensor;
 ImageView iv;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.sensor_screen);
  mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
  mSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY);
  iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
 }

 protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensor,
    SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
 }

 protected void onPause() {
  super.onPause();
  mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
 }

 public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
 }

 public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
  if (event.values[0] == 0) {
   iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.near);
  } else {
   iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.far);
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Its ok. But Proximity sensors do not always reports 1 and 0. See my answer.

Comment: @김철용. Very Nice! Working !

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `getMaximumRange()` method to obtain your proximity sensor's max range and use it to determine what to do.

```
SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
Sensor proximitySensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY);
float maxRange = proximitySensor.getMaximumRange();
```

Now use `maxRange` to do what you want to do.

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
if(maxRange == event.values[0]) {
// Do something when something is far away.
}
else {
// Do something when something is near.
}
}
```

One very important thing. The proximity sensor varies from device to device. It not always reports 1.0 and 0.0. For example my Moto G (1st Gen.) reports 3 cm as its min range and 100 cm as its max range. So its best to obtain the max range of the device's sensor and use it in your code rather then hard-coding the value.

Comment: @GuruCharan I have made some changes in my answer make sure you check it. I forgot to mention it in the first place.

Comment: Please provide me the manifest.xml file, of this app. I think it needs some permissions. The app isn't installing....

Comment: @GuruCharan yuo do not need any kind of permission for simply accessing the sensors. Try to figure out if there is any thing else in your app that might require a permission from the use. Let me know if you are unable to figure it out on your own.

Comment: Sir, I created a new app for testing your code..... But, when i install it on my INTEX  -  ANDROID 4.4 I get an error: App not Installed..... Why?

Comment: Have you selected the correct API level for building the app?
And also how are you trying to install the app in your phone?

Comment: @RaviPrakash : Yes I have recently tried it. Didn't faced any issue.

Comment: @RaviPrakash : See my answer I have also mentioned my max and min values reported by my proximity sensor and why it is not a good idea to hard code these values.